# How to convert String timestamp to milliseconds

Tags: java

I am running one query on oracle sql which returns me timestamp part of of sysdate in string
something like "16:30:0.0"
so i want to know how to convert it to milliseconds.

please help?

Comment: Have a look at DateFormat and Date.getTime() or Calendar.getTimeMillis()

Comment: Do you have to return in the form of a `String`? Returning it as a `Timestamp` seems like the best solution.

Comment: Milliseconds since when? Seems you have only the time, not a full date time.

Answer (score 2):

This is using the standard Java Date API.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
df.parse("16:06:43.233").getTime();
```

If you're using Java 8, see the new `java.time` API. If not, and you're going to do a lot of date-time-related work, see [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 1):

Use ResultSet's getTime(column)-method instead of getString(column) to avoid having to do the conversion yourself: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTime%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = sdf.parse("16:30:0.0");
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

But, this code will return milliseconds since *01.01.1970 16:30:00.000*. If you want to get millis from the current day you can do the following.

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, today.get(Calendar.MONTH));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: This will default to the user's local time zone, which will result in incorrect milliseconds if the user is not in GMT. Consider setting the timezone for the date formatter.